The Intuition Behind The Max and Min of a Dual Digital
How do we intuitively figure out what the max and min price of a dual is? We know that the factors to price a dual is the price of digital option 1 and price of digital option 2 as well as correlation.
For example, for a dual digi (both calls) with price of 1 being 0.7 and price of 2 being 0.8, we know that the min dual price (when the correlation is -1) is 0.5. But why? Why is the max 0.7 (when the correlation is 1)?

Best case, if 1 happens, then 2 also always happens. So the max is $0.7$ (if 2 happens, 1 can't always happen because the mass at 1 is lower).
Worst case, 2 happens, then 1 happens with a chance of $x$. So $0.8*x+0.2*y=0.7$ so x is minimum if $y=1$, so $x=5/8$.
So the price is $2 happens * Pr(1 happens|2 happens)$=$0.8*5/8=0.5$
If you like you can also get the max price with maximizing $x$, which happens at $x=7/8$.
